# Extract Image Area using canvas

Tags: html, canvas, html5-canvas

New to canvas...I have this image and I'd like to extract the sneaker portion --so removing all of the surrounding black pixels:

[image: shoe]

Is this possible? How would I go about doing so? Any tips/help is much appreciated

Comment: If the image is from the same domain or has a CORS header you can access the pixel data with `ctx,getImageData` then you can test each pixel for black and set the alpha channel to 0. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageData for more info and links to how to use imageData

Comment: @Blindman67 thank you for the feedback! I can set the alpha of all black pixels to 0, the issue then becomes the black pixels within the bounds become transparent as well--the ideal results would be the pixels outside of the whitelines being removed...can that be done with imageData?